# Json.NET Decimal Parsing Rounding

Tags: c#, json, json.net, decimal

Why does the single decimal get rounded but the decimals in the array do not?

```
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal,
    Culture = new CultureInfo(string.Empty)
    {
        NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo
        {
            CurrencyDecimalDigits = 5
        }
    }
};     

string jsonData = "{\"Values\": [0.0,22493194440943108.0]}";
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
decimal[] arrayOfDecimals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal[]>(jObject["Values"].ToString());
decimal singleDecimal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal>(jObject["Values"][1].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal[]>(jObject["Values"].ToString())[1]);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal>(jObject["Values"][1].ToString()));
```

Output is :

22493194440943108.0

22493194440943100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `ToString()` method, Json.NET will create a formatted string of the values it contains.  That means for `jObject["Values"].ToString()`, you get:

```
[
  0.0,
  22493194440943108.0
]
```

And for `jObject["Values"][1].ToString()`, you get:

```
2.24931944409431E+16
```

Deserialising these works, but you can see that the formatting of the singular one has resulted in some rounding.  If you really do want to call `ToString` then deserialise something you've already deserialised (using `JObject.Parse`), you can pass the `Formatting.None` option - this works as expected:

```
decimal[] arrayOfDecimals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal[]>(jObject["Values"].ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
decimal singleDecimal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal>(jObject["Values"][1].ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
```